# Group Action: Definition & Axioms

Tags: group-theory, permutations, definition, group-actions, motivation

Why is a "group action" defined as it is?  Namely, a group $G$ acting on a set $S$, that is associative and has a unit element.  This defines a monoid.  But, authors go on to claim that the actions of $G$ are homomorphisms of $g\colon G \to \mathrm{Perm}(S)$.  Permutations have inverses $g^{-1}$, which makes them into a group.  So, why not state that an inverse exists in the definition?

In addition, consider a function acting on a vector space, say $\mathrm{GL}(n,V)$, which is the set of all "invertible" $n$-dimensional linear transformations on $V$.

Comment: "Associativity" is not quite right, because an action is not an operation. In the equation $g\cdot(h\cdot x) = (gh)\cdot  x$, the left hand side has two occurrences of the action, but the right hand side has only one occurrence. So it's not "associativity", it is "compatibility" of the action with the group operation. Inverses follow from the other two conditions: because $e\cdot x = x$ for all $x$, it follows that $g\cdot x = y$ if and only if $g^{-1}\cdot y = x$.

Comment: Please use Mathjax, and please do not edit out the Mathjax that was added.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $GL(n,V)$ is incorrect. "$n$-dimensional linear transformation on $V$" is incorrect. It should be $GL(n,F)$ with $F$ a field. Linear transformations do not have dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

> So, why not state that an inverse exists in the definition?

Because it follows from the definitions.

Suppose that $G$ acts on a set $S$. Let $g \in G$. Then the map $S \rightarrow S$, $x \mapsto g \cdot x$ is a bijection, since it has a inverse: the map $x \mapsto g^{-1} \cdot x$.

To prove this, you need precisely the properties given by the definition of a group action: $1_G \cdot x = x$ and $(g_1 \cdot g_2) \cdot x = (g_1g_2) \cdot x$.